# C 3D Character Array Function Returning Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, char

```
char getStr(int x) {
    const char *arr[10] = {"test", "temp"};
    return *arr[x];
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", getStr(0));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is returning the error "EXC_BAD_ADDRESS (code=1, address=0x70)" in Xcode. What could be causing the issue?
What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: `printf`s `%s` expects a `char *`, you provide a `char`...

Comment: What do you want to get character or the string ?

Comment: That is neither a 3D nor a 2D "character" array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print a char use %c not %s in printf():

```
printf("%c", getStr(0));
```

Also, if you want to return one of the two strings you should do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* getStr(int x) {
    char* arr[2] = {"test", "temp"};
    return arr[x];
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", getStr(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, if you want to return the x-th char of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 2

char getStr(int x) {
    char* arr[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"test", "temp"};
    size_t s = strlen(arr[0]);
    int i = 0;
    while ((size_t)x > s) {
        i++;
        if (i > ARRAY_SIZE) return 0;
        x -= s;
        s = strlen(arr[i]);
    }
    return arr[i][x];
}

int main() {
    printf("%c", getStr(7));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how about `printf("%s", getStr(3));`?

Comment: Great thanks! So before I just run off with working code what mistakes was I making and what did it cause to happen?